# Can't center navbar items and hover tag

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, hover, navbar

I'm having trouble centering the items in my bootstrap navbar. I'm currently using bootstrap 3.
I read a lot of posts and tried everything I could think of, but nothing works.
I'm also trying to make a blue line appear on top of the items using 'hover', but I can't make it smaller.
Here's my code.

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: transparent;
  padding-top: 30px;
  /* border: 0; */
}

.navbar a {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Ruda, sans-serif;
}

.navbar-brand {
  max-height: 40px;
}

.navbar-nav>li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  padding-right: 80px;
}

.navbar-nav>li:hover {
  border-top: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

To override some classes in bootstrap u have to use `@media` rule.
Also I changed behavior on hover to just change color not all border. It will avoid flickering.

```css
@media (min-width: 768px){
    ul.navbar-nav{
        table-layout: fixed;
        display: table;
        margin: 0 auto;
        float: none;
    }
}

.navbar 
{
  background-color: transparent; 
  padding-top: 30px;
}


.navbar a
{
  font-size: 15px;
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase; 
  font-family: Ruda, sans-serif;
}

.navbar-brand
{
  max-height: 40px;
}

.navbar-nav > li {
    display: inline-block;
    float:none;
  padding-right:80px;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent
}

.navbar-nav > li:hover
{
  border-top-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar-header" >
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 5</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I thank you for the 'border-top-color' tip, but this doesn't answer my questions. The likes of 'page x' and 'home' are still not centered and the top border on hover is still too big.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i understood well your problem, but u just removed the padding on the ".navbar-nav li" and the blue line is smalle and the text is centered

```css
.navbar 
{
  background-color: transparent; 
  padding-top: 30px;
  /* border: 0; */
}


.navbar a
{
  font-size: 15px;
  color: black;
  text-align:center !important;
  text-transform: uppercase; 
  font-family: Ruda, sans-serif;
}

.navbar-brand
{
  max-height: 40px;
}

.navbar-nav > li {
    display: inline-block;
    float:none;
}

.navbar-nav > li:hover
{
  border-top: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar-header" >
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 5</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```